# Excel - VBA Web Scraping - getElementsByTagName

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, getelementsbytagname

I am running this code and it shows perfectly these track & field performances I want to get:

```
Sub WebScraping()

Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim Records As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Record As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLIms As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLIm As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Dim URL As String
Dim RowNum As Integer: RowNum = 1

Dim NumPage As Integer

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:z10000").ClearContents

For NumPage = 1 To 4

    URL = "https://www.worldathletics.org/records/toplists/sprints/100-metres/outdoor/men/senior/2020?page=" & NumPage & ""
    
    XMLPage.Open "Get", URL, False
    XMLPage.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    
    XMLPage.send
    
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText
    
    Set Records = HTMLDoc.getElementById("toplists").getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
    
    For Each Record In Records

        Set HTMLIms = Record.getElementsByTagName("td")
    
            For Each HTMLIm In HTMLIms
        
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = HTMLIms.Item(0).innerText
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNum, 2).Value = HTMLIms.Item(1).innerText
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNum, 3).Value = HTMLIms.Item(2).innerText
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNum, 4).Value = HTMLIms.Item(3).innerText
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNum, 5).Value = HTMLIms.Item(4).innerText
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNum, 6).Value = HTMLIms.Item(5).innerText
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNum, 7).Value = HTMLIms.Item(6).innerText
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNum, 9).Value = HTMLIms.Item(8).innerText
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNum, 10).Value = HTMLIms.Item(9).innerText
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNum, 11).Value = HTMLIms.Item(10).innerText
    
            Next HTMLIm
            
            RowNum = RowNum + 1
    Next Record

Next NumPage

End Sub
```

But I have problems when I want to insert a code to get the athlete's id (that also works well separately):

```
'Athletes' codes
RowNum = 1
Set HTMLIms = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    
For Each HTMLIm In HTMLIms
    If Left(HTMLIm.getAttribute("href"), 24) = "about:/athletes/athlete=" Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNum, 12).Value = Right(HTMLIm.getAttribute("href"), Len(HTMLIm.getAttribute("href")) - _
    (InStr(HTMLIm.getAttribute("href"), "=")))
    RowNum = RowNum + 1
    End If
Next HTMLIm
```

Could somebody please help me about how to insert the second code inside first?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to include the id numbers in one go. I've used a little trick in order for you to get the `+` or `-` sign right next to different numbers in column 3. You can merge the rest as I pasted here the relevant portion.

Partially merged code:

```
Sub WebScraping()
    Const Url As String = "https://www.worldathletics.org/records/toplists/sprints/100-metres/outdoor/men/senior/2020?page="
    Dim XMLPage As New XMLHTTP60, HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim Record As Object, NumPage As Integer
    Dim RowNum As Integer, Ws As Worksheet, I&
    
    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For NumPage = 1 To 2
        XMLPage.Open "Get", Url & NumPage, False
        XMLPage.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        XMLPage.send
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText
    
        For Each Record In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
            RowNum = RowNum + 1: Ws.Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = Record.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(0).innerText
            Ws.Cells(RowNum, 2).Value = Record.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(1).innerText
            Ws.Cells(RowNum, 3).Value = "'" & Record.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(2).innerText
            Ws.Cells(RowNum, 4).Value = Record.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(3).innerText
            On Error Resume Next
            Ws.Cells(RowNum, 5).Value = Split(Record.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(3).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).getAttribute("href"), "=")(1)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next Record
    Next NumPage
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot SIM. Would you be so kind to show me the complete merged code? I get an error so I asume I probably did it wrongly.

Comment: No error anymore but it's not working well for me. It lists each row 11 times and it doesn't show the athlete's code. Please shee this screenshot: https://gyazo.com/3336cb3532ecd3d3183ab5b828908039

Comment: Select the entire sheet and press delete button and then run the code. It seems it's the issue of your spreadsheet.

Comment: I used a new destination Sheet and it works about athlete's code (previous probably had another format) but still 11 repetitions of each performance.

Comment: It's because of the the way you have written your code in the first place. I've fixed it. Try now. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect now! Thanks a lot. I will try to study this code. Let me ask you it you know some website, blog, book(s) where I could learn more sistematically about this web scraping code...